# Non-Fatal reports not logging

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I am logging non fatal errors in my service file after a network request but it is not logging until i restart the app, that is when it gets logged in crashlytics is there a way i can log it immediately?

```
let err = NSError(domain: String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil", code: response.response?.statusCode ?? 0, userInfo: ["Hello": "This is an info"])
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(err)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, as (emphasis mine):

> When you log an NSError, the app does not immediately terminate. Because **Crashlytics only sends the logged error report on the next app launch**,

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#log_non-fatal_exceptions)